# How to correctly set a WH_KEYBOARD hook procedure using SetWindowsHookExW in rust?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I believe I have correctly set the [WH_KEYBOARD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)) hook*, yet it doesn't seem to be working.
When running the code shown below and writing two lines I would expect the following output:

```
0
<something>
<something something>
<Number of times the hook procedure was called>  # Sadly this stays at 0
```

What am I doing wrong?
Using `println!("Hello World")` inplace of `FOO += 1` doesn't work either. Or at least it doesn't print `Hello World` hence leaves me doubtful whether the function has been called at all.

**Am I not setting the hook correctly?**

Or is my understanding of what triggers the hook wrong?

* According to the [SetWindowsHookExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) documentation.

*Cargo.toml*:

```
[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.44.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
    "Win32_System_Threading",
]
```

*main.rs*:

```
use windows::Win32::{
    Foundation::{HINSTANCE, LPARAM, LRESULT, WPARAM},
    System::Threading::GetCurrentThreadId,
    UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{
        CallNextHookEx, SetWindowsHookExW, UnhookWindowsHookEx, HHOOK, WH_KEYBOARD,
    },
};

static mut FOO: u32 = 0u32;

unsafe extern "system" fn low_level_keyboard_proc_callback(
    code: i32,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    FOO += 1;
    return CallNextHookEx(HHOOK::default(), code, wparam, lparam);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { println!("{}", FOO) };
    let hook_handle = unsafe {
        SetWindowsHookExW(
            WH_KEYBOARD,
            Some(low_level_keyboard_proc_callback),
            HINSTANCE::default(),
            GetCurrentThreadId(),
        )
        .unwrap()
    };
    for _ in 0..2 {
        let mut line = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
        drop(line);
    }
    unsafe {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook_handle);
    }
    unsafe { println!("{}", FOO) };
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant There's an `.unwrap()` call, that turns an error return value into a `panic!`. That's pretty hard to ignore. The actual issue is failure to dispatch messages. As spelled out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)): *"The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**"* The easiest way to spin up a message loop is having the system do it for you (e.g. with a call to `MessageBoxW`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) in Windows come in many different shapes and sizes. Each one has different requirements with implications for clients.

In case of a [`WH_KEYBOARD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)) the remarks section of the documentation provides vital information, specifically this:

> This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**

The code in question, however, does not dispatch messages, and so the hook procedure never gets called. It could be updated with an explicit [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew)/[`DispatchMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessagew) loop, or take advantage of a system-provided message loop.

The latter is both simpler as well as allowing you to request program termination, so let's just do that:

```rust
fn main() {
    unsafe { println!("{}", FOO) };
    let hook_handle = unsafe {
        SetWindowsHookExW(
            WH_KEYBOARD,
            Some(low_level_keyboard_proc_callback),
            HINSTANCE::default(),
            GetCurrentThreadId(),
        )
        .unwrap()
    };
    let _ = unsafe { MessageBoxW(None, w!("Click OK to exit"), w!("Test"), MB_OK) };
    unsafe {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook_handle);
    }
    unsafe { println!("{}", FOO) };
}
```

With that, pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key to dismiss the message box will result in an output of `2` (i.e. one `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` cycle).

---

While that fixes the issue asked about, there's still another one lingering: The code sets up a callback that's called by the system, and returns into system code again. Since the default panic strategy is `"unwind"`, that'll lead to undefined behavior as unwinding crosses into foreign stack frames.

To remedy this, the *Cargo.toml* file should set the [panic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#panic) strategy to `"abort"` for all profiles.

Comment: How would a GetMessageW/DispatchMessageW loop look like that doesn't open a dedicated window but uses the console window itself?

Comment: You don't own the console window (it belongs to another process) -- that would require finding and subclassing the console window, which is fraught. It's simple enough to create a minimal offscreen or hidden window for your message loop. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues