# How to reliably PeekConsoleInput in a background thread while reading lines from stdin in main thread?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

##### TL; DR:

I need to retrieve the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s* from the console input buffer in real time without preventing a parallel/the main thread from reading them and printing the characters to the console screen buffer.

All I manage to achieve is to either retrieve the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s using [PeekConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) (or [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)) **OR** have the main thread handle reading/printing the typed characters to the screen.

**How can I reliably peek at the console input buffer and retrieve the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s while letting the main thread handle printing the typed characters to the screen?**

* preferably only [KEY_EVENT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str)s

---

I can use the following two lines to have my console application print to the screen whatever the user types on the keyboard (including the deletion of characters in case of `backspace` or `delete` as well as inserting characters by use of the arrow keys):

```rust
let mut line = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
```

[image: console_input]

I would like to keep that behavior while retrieving the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s from the console input buffer.**

I tried using [PeekConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) in a background thread and keep the above code in the main thread but the main thread seems to be faster in taking the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s out of the input buffer leaving no records for the background thread to peek at.

The attached code shows how running [PeekConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) in a background thread does successfully peek the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s as long as no other thread removes them (`flush = true` vs `flush = false`).

**How can I reliably peek at the console input buffer and retrieve the [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s while letting the main thread handle printing the typed characters to the screen?**

** I can then send those [INPUT_RECORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str)s to child processes and using [WriteConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput) replicate the users input on multiple consoles simultaneously.

---

*Cargo.toml*

```
[dependencies]
tokio = {version = "1.27.0", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread", "time"]}

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.44.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_Console",
]
```

*main.rs*

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use windows::Win32::System::Console::{
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer, GetStdHandle, PeekConsoleInputW, INPUT_RECORD, STD_INPUT_HANDLE,
};

async fn peek_console_input(nb_of_records_to_read: u32, flush: bool) {
    const NB_EVENTS: usize = 2;
    let mut nb_of_records_read = 0;
    let console_handle = unsafe { GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE).unwrap() };
    loop {
        let mut input_buffer: [INPUT_RECORD; NB_EVENTS] = [INPUT_RECORD::default(); NB_EVENTS];
        let mut number_of_events_read = 0;
        unsafe {
            PeekConsoleInputW(
                console_handle,
                &mut input_buffer,
                &mut number_of_events_read,
            )
            .expect("Failed to read console input");
        }
        if number_of_events_read > 0 as u32 {
            if flush {
                unsafe {
                    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(console_handle);
                };
            }
            nb_of_records_read += number_of_events_read;
            for record in input_buffer {
                let event = unsafe { record.Event.KeyEvent };
                println!(
                    "key_down: {}, unicode_char: {}",
                    event.bKeyDown.as_bool(),
                    unsafe { event.uChar.UnicodeChar }
                );
            }
        }
        if nb_of_records_read >= nb_of_records_to_read {
            break;
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let nb_of_records_to_read = 8;
    for flush in [true, false] {
        println!(
            "Spawning a thread peeking at the console input buffer \
            for the next {nb_of_records_to_read} input records \
            (key down and up count as 1 record each)"
        );
        let join_handle = tokio::spawn(peek_console_input(nb_of_records_to_read, flush));
        if flush {
            println!(
                "Putting main thread to sleep for 2 milliseconds at a time \
                while waiting for the background thread to finish."
            );
            println!("Please press any combination of keys and behold the output");
            while !join_handle.is_finished() {
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2)).await;
            }
        } else {
            println!("Main thread is reading a line from stdin, please start pressing keys");
            let mut line = String::new();
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            println!("read line: {}", line);
        }
        join_handle.abort();
        join_handle.await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is doomed to failure as there's no way to synchronize the console's input buffer between the threads. You might try hooking ReadConsoleInput() and posting the events to a worker thread instead.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights! Do you mean using LD_PRELOAD[1]to replace ReadConsoleInput with my own function that sends the events to a worker before returning?
Does something like `std::io::stdin().read_line()` call that function under the hood?

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: Why not simply use a `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD)` hook to get the keystokes before the console delivers them to `ReadConsoleInput()`?

Comment: I sort of tried that[1] but got deterred by the required GetMessage/DispatchMessage loop. I'll definitely give it another try [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870904/how-to-correctly-set-a-wh-keyboard-hook-procedure-using-setwindowshookexw-in-rus